# How to run Postman Teams cloud collection with Newman CLI

Tags: postman

Is it possible to use Newman to run a collection that is situated on Postman Teams Cloud? I do not want to keep a copy of the collection in my code base.

I am currently running a collection of Postman tests with Newman in my CI process by exporting the collection and keeping it in my code base and then running them by executing a command with the Newman CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run newman using a url instead of a file you just need to have the collection Id on hand then you can do something like:

```
newman run $url -g globals.json -e env.json --reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export $resultsFile
```

You would still need to have your global (if any) and any environment you use exported onto a file. You'll also need to setup an API key if you haven't already done so.

You can get all your collections from https://api.getpostman.com/collections

What I do as well is get the environment from the cloud as well so that I always have the latest, I've been beaten a couple of times already with failing tests due to having an old copy of the environment. You can get the environment Ids from https://api.getpostman.com/environments then use it to retrieve the environment.

Here's a reference to the API: https://docs.api.getpostman.com/?_ga=2.190073579.1786927008.1553548647-42383958.1544126601